# JS not working in Firefox, works in IE and Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox

Was wondering if anyone could provide some insight as to why this js does not work in Firefox but works perfectly and as intended under IE and Chrome?

It changes the color of a lot of divs when hovering over some buttons at the top of the page.

Can be seen on my site: ptable.info

```
window.onload=function(){
var noblegasesColl = document.getElementsByClassName('noblegases');
var halogensColl = document.getElementsByClassName('halogens');
var othernonmetalsColl = document.getElementsByClassName('othernonmetals');
var transitionmetalsColl = document.getElementsByClassName('transitionmetals');
var metalloidsColl = document.getElementsByClassName('metalloids');
var posttransitionColl = document.getElementsByClassName('posttransition');
var alkalineColl = document.getElementsByClassName('alkaline');
var alkaliColl = document.getElementsByClassName('alkali');
var actinoidsColl = document.getElementsByClassName('actinoids');
var lanthanoidsColl = document.getElementsByClassName('lanthanoids');

//Noble Gases
document.getElementById('noblegasesButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#696969');
});
document.getElementById('noblegasesButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});
//Halogens
document.getElementById('halogensButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#696969');
});

document.getElementById('halogensButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#3399CC');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});
//Non-metals
document.getElementById('nonmetalsButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#696969');                    
});

document.getElementById('nonmetalsButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#3399CC');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});
//Transition metals
document.getElementById('transitionmetalsButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#696969');        
});

document.getElementById('transitionmetalsButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#3399CC');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});
//Post-transition
document.getElementById('posttransitionButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#696969');
});

document.getElementById('posttransitionButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#3399CC');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});
//Metalloids
document.getElementById('metalloidsButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#696969');
});

document.getElementById('metalloidsButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#3399CC');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});
//Alkaline
document.getElementById('alkalineButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#696969');
});

document.getElementById('alkalineButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#3399CC');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});
//Alkali
document.getElementById('alkaliButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#696969');
});

document.getElementById('alkaliButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#3399CC');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});
//Lanthanoids
document.getElementById('lanthanoidsButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969');
});

document.getElementById('lanthanoidsButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#3399CC');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});
//Actinoids
document.getElementById('actinoidsButton').addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#696969');
});

document.getElementById('actinoidsButton').addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    changeColor(halogensColl, '#00FFFF');
    changeColor(othernonmetalsColl, '#7CFC00');
    changeColor(transitionmetalsColl, '#ff78bb');
    changeColor(metalloidsColl, '#7A378B');
    changeColor(posttransitionColl, '#8FBC8F');
    changeColor(alkalineColl, '#e5e500');
    changeColor(alkaliColl, '#FF6600');
    changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#3399CC');
    changeColor(lanthanoidsColl, '#CC1100');
    changeColor(actinoidsColl, '#f4a460');
});

}

function changeColor(coll, color){

    for(var i=0, len=coll.length; i<len; i++)
    {
        coll[i].style["background-color"] = color;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working? Can you put `console errors` as well

Comment: Hovering over the buttons at the top does not do anything in Firefox, but it does change the colors of the divs on IE and Chrome as intended.

Comment: By the way, I am not able to access the site URL mentioned in question. My request is getting rejected.

Comment: Sorry - the url is working now

Comment: @Harry that fixed it - I suspected that it would be something small like that. Thank you :)

Comment: You also have an inconsistency on the mouseover/out with halogensButton  and changeColor(noblegasesColl, '#696969'); PS: If you use jQuery, your script could be a 10th in size and the code would work in IE<9 too as a bonus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use either `style.backgroundColor` or `style['backgroundColor']` to set the background-color. Either of these methods should work across browsers. I have tested in FireFox 23, Opera 15, Chrome 31 (Dev Build) and IE10.

You can refer [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/xH42x/2/) for a sample fiddle. The fiddle has three `div` with `id` as `aa`, `bb` and `cc` respectively.

When you do `mouseover` and `mouseout`, you will find that it affects all three `div` in Chrome, IE10 and Opera. But in FireFox, it affects only the first and third `div` because the second `div` uses `style['background-color']` and is not recognized by FireFox.